# android - Копирование базы данных из одной data/data в свою data/data

Tags: android, terminal, база-данных

Делаю приложение для разлочки (разблокировки телефона от привязки оператора). Нужно скопировать базу данных настроек из /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db в свои данные (в data/data/com.albatros.nck.hacker/databases/

```
 try
    {
        java.lang.Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        java.lang.Process busybox = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("busybox");
        java.lang.Process make_folder = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkdir /data/data/ru.albatros.nck.hacker/databases");
        java.lang.Process hack_copy_db = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db data/data/ru.albatros.nck.hacker/databases/");

    }
    catch (IOException e)
{}
```

Вот так :D
При запуске появляется окошко для подтверждения root-прав, создается папка databases в data/data/ru.albatros.nck.hacker но в ней не оказывается базы данных. Почему? В приложении "Терминал" команда работает отлично. Что не так?

Comment: а покажите, какие именно команды в терминале выполняются

Comment: @metalurgus, все :D код в вопросе, команды в кавычках. Но приложение не выполняет эту команду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все ваши комманды выполняются в разных сессиях и друг на друга не влияют.

Делайте:

```
try
    {
        java.lang.Process make_folder = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su 0 mkdir -p /data/data/ru.albatros.nck.hacker/databases");
        java.lang.Process hack_copy_db = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su 0 cp /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db /data/data/ru.albatros.nck.hacker/databases/");

    }
    catch (IOException e)
{}
```