# android - Работа с базой данных настроек

Tags: android, root, sqlite

Необходимо...

1) Взять базу данных из `data/data/com.android.provider.settings/databases/settings.db`

2) Далее нужно добавить в нее новую строчку

3) Поставить измененную базу данных на место.

Как выполнить первый пункт?  Сначала я запрашиваю `root` доступ

```
try  {
java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
}
catch (IOException e){}
```

Появляется окошко подтверждения выдачи `root`, нажимаю "Access". Далее по идее должен выполниться этот код

```
try {
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

if (sd.canWrite()) {
String currentDBPath = "/data/data/" + "com.android.providers.settings" + "/databases/settings.db";
String backupDBPath = "data.db";
File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

if (currentDB.exists()) {
FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
src.close();
dst.close();
}}} catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), 1).show();
}
```

Но, в `Toast` пишет:

```
.....EACCESS: Permission denied
```

Добавил в `AndroidManifest.xml` разрешения:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ru.albatros.testroot" 
>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
...
```

И это **ничего** не дает. Как? Приложение получило `root`, но всё равно нет какого-то разрешения. Тестирую на Android 5.1.1 (CyanogenMod 12.1, кастомная прошивка). Помогите, оказывается, все сложнее, чем я думал.

Comment: Неужели вы с июля месяца не смогли разобраться с http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547500/217000 ?

Comment: Уже все) Через команду `settings put system <key> <value>` без всяких манипуляций добавляю сразу в бд